# Why can't django-configurations pick up a SECRET_KEY environment variable from a heroku environment?

Tags: django, environment-variables, heroku

When trying to deploy a *django* app to heroku using [*django-configurations*](https://github.com/jezdez/django-configurations), I keep getting the error:

> ValueError: Couldn't setup configuration 'config.settings.Production':  Secret value 'SECRET_KEY' is not set

However, when I run `heroku config:get SECRET_KEY`, I do get a result. It is the same value that set it to. I randomly generated a string on my local environment and set that string to the environment value `SECRET_KEY` by running `heroku config_set SECRET_KEY=ASFASDF`

The appropriate line with my *settings.py* file is:

```
SECRET_KEY = values.SecretValue()
```

I can't figure out why *django-configurations* doesn't seem to be able to pick up this particular environment variable ...

Answer (score 2):

after reading_the_source_code for django_configurations, I discovered that the value that it is actually looking for by default is DJANGO_SECRET_KEY. Setting the environment variable to that instead made everything work out.